# Проверка на существование файла или директории PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap, android, javascript, cordova, файлы

собственно сабж, как можно узнать существует ли тот или иной файл или папка в запрошенной директории? Погуглил малеха, но так и не нашел ответа, есть ли такие функции в **Cordova API** или в File API ? Прошу помощи так как сам не нашел нужного мне. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileSource = /*File path*/

reader.onloadend = function (evt) {

    if (evt.target.result == null) {
        /*no file*/
    } else {
        /*file*/
    }
};

reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```

Comment: спасибо попробую